# if every finitely generated $R$-module has Finite Free Resolution, then every finitely generated $R[x]$-module also has it

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, polynomial-rings

I am reading the Rotman's book "*An Introduction to Homological Algebra*" and I do not understand the part of the proof of theorem 8.47 in page 481.

**Theorem 8.47** Let R be a commutative noetherian ring. If every finitely generated R-module has Finite Free Resolution (FFR), then every finitely generated R[x]-module has Finite Free Resolution (FFR).

One step of the proof is based on proving the following:

**if $M$ is a finitely generated $R[x]$-module such that $ann(M) \cap R  \neq \{0\}$, then $M$ has FFR.**

Here is the proof in Rotman's book:
Let $m\in M$ be nonzero and let $I= ann(m) \cap R\neq 0$ be the R-ideal. We have that $R/I\simeq \langle m \rangle_R$ the R-submodule of $M$ generated by $m$.
Because R[x] is a flat R-module, we have the following exact sequence:
$$0 \to R[x] \otimes_R I \to R[x] \to R[x] \otimes_R \langle m\rangle_R \to 0 $$

Rotman concludes that the R[x]-module $R[x] \otimes_R \langle m\rangle_R \simeq R[x]/(R[x]\otimes_R I) \simeq R[x]/(R[x]I)$ is a **cyclic submodule of $M$**.

It is clear that it is cyclic, but **why is it a submodule of $M$**?

If we define a $R[x]$-homomorphism
$\phi:R[x] \otimes_R \langle m\rangle_R \to M$ by $\phi(p(x)\otimes_R m) = p(x)m$, I think that this may not be injective since $ann(m)\neq 0$

It is immediate that $R[x] \otimes_R \langle m\rangle_R$ has FFR, but would not it conclude the same if $I=0$. I do not see in which part of the proof the condition $I\neq 0$ is used.

Comment: I reproduce here a comment of Alex Wertheim giving a counterexample to Rotman's claim (this book is nice, but it has many errors): "Consider the following example: set $R = \mathbb{Z}, M = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ with the usual $\mathbb{Z}$-module structure, and let $X$ act by the endomorphism given by projection onto the second factor. Take $m = (1, 0)$; then $I = 2\mathbb{Z}$, and indeed, $R/I$ embeds into $M$ as the copy of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$. But the $\mathbb{Z}[X]$-submodule of $M$ generated by $m$ is likewise still $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, since $Xm = 0$ [...]"

Comment: To fill in the missing details, note that $R[X]\otimes_R Rm = \mathbb Z/2 [X]$ in this case but $R[X]m = \mathbb Z/2$, and the natural map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: As a minor aside, I should note that my example is not quite as counterexample to Rotman's claim as given, since it does not satisfy $ann(M) \cap R \neq 0$. But I think this can easily be modified by taking $M$ to be $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with no other changes.